# Fastest way to compute Gaussian kernel vector in CppArmadillo?

Tags: c++, optimization, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to compute a vector of gaussian kernel evaluations as quickly as possible. I have a data point x in R^p, and a matrix X of n vectors x_i. I would like to compute  exp( -||x-x_i||^2 / t) for every x_i and return the result as a vector.

I have tried implementing this in both R and RcppArmadillo via the following code

R CODE:

```
kernel <- function(x, Data, sigma){
  if(sigma <= 0 ) stop('Gaussian kernel parameter <= 0.')

  DiffPart <- (t(t(Data) - x))^2  ## Computes the distance squared of the data and point x
  DiffPart <- rowSums(DiffPart)  # Sum of squares
  exp( - DiffPart / sigma)  #Divide by kernel parameter and evluate exponential function
}
```

RcppArmadillo:

```
arma::Col<double> kernelCPP(arma::Row<double> x, arma::Mat<double> Data, double sigma){
  arma::Mat<double> Diff=Data.each_row()-x;
  int n = Data.n_rows;
  arma::Col<double> kern(n);
  for(int k = 0 ; k < n; k++){
    kern(k) = exp(-arma::accu(square(Diff.row(k)))/sigma);
  }
  return(kern);
}
```

Unfortunately, my RcppArmadillo code is not much faster than the original R code. I'll be computing kernel vectors hundreds of thousands of times in future code/computation, and so I would like this to be as fast of a process as I can make it.

When microbenchmarking, I get the following results:

```
> microbenchmark(
+   kernel(x= TrainX1[1,], Data = TrainX1, sigma = 100)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq   mean   median
  2.223359 2.274559 2.5199 2.308052
       uq     max neval
 2.575144 4.73301   100
```

and

```
> microbenchmark(
+   kernelCPP(x= TrainX1[1,], Data = TrainX1, sigma = 100)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
    min       lq     mean
 1.697706 1.732053 1.826743
   median       uq      max neval
 1.775786 1.871786 2.493439   100
```

A little faster, but not by much.

Comment: you know armadillo is vectorized: you could do `return exp(-sum(square(Data.each_row()-x),1)/sigma);` for your function. Also remember the R you are using is already optimized. C++ will be faster in case you are using R's for loops. Other than that, the optimized R functions will compete with C++. For example, try writing your SumC and compare with R's sum, R's sum will be faster.

Comment: Comment is generally correct but local C++-based functions are often _marginally_ faster as R does a bit of extra checking for `NA` and other corner cases.  But the basic gist is true:  if R uses efficient vectorised code (as it does in basic arithmetic), you will gain little.  One can gain on loops, function, calls, and other more complex ops.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Looks like I'll need to speed up my code elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexLapanowski There is already a function in armadillo to do that: [normpdf()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#normpdf). The function internally uses OpenMP parallelization to speed things up.

Comment: @Onyambu I tested SumC as a for loop and it was faster by 60%, That might be "marginal" depending on your perspective, but I generally find Rcpp to be always faster.

Comment: @thc click [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) under vector input-scalar output and you will note that the R's sum function is faster than the written sumC even though R's sum still has to check for NA and corner cases.

Comment: @Onyambu yes, I'm saying that that function is 60% faster on my machine, tested with `microbenchmark`.  I don't know what the difference is, but I wonder if it's because of an outdated Rcpp version in that tutorial?  Or perhaps because I'm using -O3 optimization by default?

Comment: @tch read Dirk Eddelbuettel comment. He is the author of Rcpp

Comment: @Onyambu -- I know.  Please test it out for yourself.  It is always important to benchmark and not just rely on intuition.  `x=rnorm(1e7); microbenchmark(sum(x), sumc(x))` reports 8.03 ms for `sumc` and 13.7 ms for `sum`.  The difference in Hadley's tutorial is that he's using a shorter vector, so dispatch accounts for `sumc` being slower in that case.  But I think it is accurate to say the Rcpp code is inherently faster.

Comment: @thc yes yes. I Understand what you mean. Of course the C++ in a way will be marginally faster since it does not test for anything. It just sums. On the other hand, the optimized R's sum function has to test for various corner cases before it sums. Thats why c++ will be marginally faster. But remember for, any vectorized function, if you do not need to test for anything then you can write your own function but otherwise use R's since they are optimized unless it is becoming too slow